# Custom Listview - determine if the image is clicked?

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom `ListView` which has an `ImageView`, `Textview` and `CheckBox`.

In the activity I can register if the `ListView` Item is pressed by the following code, it they press an item anywhere in the `ListView` item it just checks a `CheckBox` and my adapter is updated.

```
lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long row) {

//code
}
```

But is there a way to determine if the `ImageView` was pressed?  So if they press the image I can do something else?

Comment: You can set an `OnClickListener()` on the `ImageView` in the `Adapter`'s `getView()`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, my list contains actual images, and images of folders.  So if they click a folder I don't want anything to happen.  I'm not sure how to do this from the get View adapter.  Anyway to have the listener in the main activity where the List is?>